# Regex matching first occurrence only?

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

This is the problem:

Code:

```
Dim findtext As String = "(?<=<hello>)(.*?)(?=</hello>)"
Dim myregex As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim doregex As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex, findtext)
MsgBox(doregex(0).ToString)
```

TextBox1:

```
<hello>1</hello>
<hello>2</hello>
<hello>3</hello>
```

So, when i run the code, it shows MsgBox with `1`. Why only 1? Why not 2 and 3?

I added `?` to `.*`, but it's still the same.

Comment: you need to iterate over match object to find all matches

Comment: Better use it with LINQ, it all becomes much easier.

Comment: LINQ is shit and @Xen already did best solution, no need to hate him and suggest me what to do because you didn't answered best solution :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MatchCollection` contains multiple items but you are only retrieving the first one with `doregex(0)`. Use a loop to get to the others:

```
Dim doregex As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex, findtext)
For Each match As Match In doregex
    MsgBox(match.ToString)
Next
```

**EDIT:**

To combine the values, append them to a String within the loop before you use it:

```
Dim doregex As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex, findtext)
Dim matches As String = ""  ' consider StringBuilder if there are many matches
For Each match As Match In doregex
    matches = matches + match.ToString + " " 
Next
```

MsgBox(matches)

Comment: Seems to work, but can it combine all them into one MsgBox instead of creating new ones every time it matches? Thanks

Comment: @StefanĐorđević See [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Can't get it 100%, but thank you anyway, i did what i needed! <3

Answer (score 1):

Because you show only the first item in `MatchCollection` , you can use `For Each` loop to show all items like this :

```
For Each item In doregex
    MsgBox(item.ToString)
Next
```

You can combine items with many way, belows one of them :

```
Dim result As String = String.Empty
For Each item In doregex
    result = String.Format("{0} {1}", result, item)
Next
MsgBox(result)
```

Comment: Yeah, works pretty well, but can it combine 1, 2 and 3 into one MsgBox instead of opening new one for each? Thanks

Comment: you can see answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ:

```
Dim text_box_text = "<hello>1</hello>" & vbLf & "<hello>2</hello>" & vbLf & "<hello>3</hello>"
Dim findtext As String = "(?<=<hello>)(.*?)(?=</hello>)"
Dim my_matches_1 As List(Of String) = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text_box_text, findtext) _
                                     .Cast(Of Match)() _
                                     .Select(Function(m) m.Value) _
                                     .ToList()
MsgBox(String.Join(vbLf, my_matches_1))
```

[image]

Also, with this code, you do not need to use the resource-consuming lookarounds. Change the regex to

```
Dim findtext As String = "<hello>(.*?)</hello>"
```

and use `.Select(Function(m) m.Groups(1).Value)` instead of `.Select(Function(m) m.Value)`.